# Diagonalizing eigensystem to find normal modes of coupled oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, coupled-oscillators

I've two equations of motion that arose in a coupled oscillators in a magnetic field $\rightarrow$ continuum problem in classical mechanics:

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\omega^2 X &=& - \omega_0^2 X (2 - 2 \cos(ka))-i \omega_B \omega Y \\
-\omega^2 Y &=& - \omega_0^2 Y (2 - 2 \cos(ka))+i \omega_B \omega X
\end{eqnarray*}

My professor's solution to this problem stated that "The eigensystem is easily diagonalized by switching to"

\begin{eqnarray*}
q &=& X+ iY \\
\bar{q} &=& X - iY
\end{eqnarray*}

to find

\begin{eqnarray*}
-\omega^2 q &=& - \omega_0^2 q (2 - 2 \cos(ka))- \omega_B \omega q \\
-\omega^2 \bar{q} &=& - \omega_0^2 \bar{q} (2 - 2 \cos(ka))+ \omega_B \omega \bar{q}
\end{eqnarray*}

He then immediately states that $q$ and $\bar{q}$, or rather

$$
q_s = X + s I Y,
$$ with $s= \pm$ "are the eigenmodes"

I write the $I$ as he does, in my mind an eigenmode is a vector, so presumably this $I$ is

$$
I=\begin{pmatrix}
i & 0 \\
0 & i
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but I could be wrong!

My confusion lies in what's going on here:
why does "diagonalizing the eigensystem" give us the normal/eigenmodes? Also HOW does switching to $q$ and $\bar{q}$ "diagonalize the eigensystem"?

Comment: While the background for the question comes from a physics context, the actual question is about linear algebra, not physics.

Comment: Why are you lost in so many omega's, exponents, subscripts etc. Start with these so simple expressions
\begin{align}
\rho X & \boldsymbol{=+}i\sigma Y
\tag{1}\label{1}\\
\rho Y & \boldsymbol{=-}i\sigma X
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align} 
where
\begin{equation}
\rho\boldsymbol{=}\omega^2\boldsymbol{-}\left[2 - 2 \cos\left(ka\right)\right]\omega^2_0\,,\qquad \sigma\boldsymbol{=}\omega_B \omega
\tag{3}\label{3}
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

you can write your equation with matrix and vector notation:

$$ \underbrace{\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -{\omega}^{2}-2\,{\omega_{{0}}}^{2}+2\,{
\omega_{{0}}}^{2}\cos \left( {\it ka} \right) &i\omega_{{B}}\omega
\\  -i\omega_{{B}}\omega&-{\omega}^{2}-2\,{\omega_{{0
}}}^{2}+2\,{\omega_{{0}}}^{2}\cos \left( {\it ka} \right) \end {array}
 \right] }_{\boldsymbol A}
\,\begin{bmatrix}
   X \\
   Y \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
   0 \\
   0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

with

$$q_1=X+i\,Y~,q_2=X-i\,Y\tag 1$$

you obtain

$$\begin{bmatrix}
   X \\
   Y \\
 \end{bmatrix}=\underbrace{\frac 12 \,\left[ \begin {array}{cc} 1&1\\ -i&i\end {array}
 \right]}_{Q} \,\begin{bmatrix}
   q_1 \\
   q_2 \\
 \end{bmatrix}
$$
$\Rightarrow$

$$A\mapsto Q^{-1}\,A\,Q=\underbrace{\left[ \begin {array}{cc} -{\omega}^{2}-2\,{\omega_{{0}}}^{2}+2\,{
\omega_{{0}}}^{2}\cos \left( {\it ka} \right) -\omega_{{B}}\omega&0
\\  0&-{\omega}^{2}-2\,{\omega_{{0}}}^{2}+2\,{\omega_
{{0}}}^{2}\cos \left( {\it ka} \right) +\omega_{{B}}\omega\end {array}
 \right] }_{A_Q}
$$

you see that the matrix is now diagonal this means that the eigenvalues are the diagonal elements and the eigenvectors are
$$~\begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}~ \text{and} \begin{bmatrix}
      0 \\
      1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

thus the Eq. (1) transformed the matrix A to diagonal shape with the unity eigenvectors

Comment: Thank you so much for this! Lastly, how are the q_1 and q_2 the eigen(normal) modes of motion? Arent the eigenvectors unity like you write?

Comment: \begin{align*}
  &\text{if A is diagonal matrix then}\\
 &T^{-1}\,A\,T\overset{!}{=}A\\
 &\text{where}~ T=\begin{bmatrix}
                    \vec q_1 & \vec q_2 \\
                  \end{bmatrix}\\
 &\text{and $~\vec{q}_i ~$ the eigen vectors, so $~T=I_2$}\\\\
 &X=\left[ \begin {array}{c} 1/2\\ 1/2\end {array}
 \right]\\
 &Y=\left[ \begin {array}{c} -1/2\,i\\ 1/2\,i
\end {array} \right]    
 \end{align*}

Comment: still a bit confused how the normal modes arise/i.e. where you stop in the problem and say, ok got it those are my normal modes